# azure - operation logs api

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to Azure and hit a roadblock. I am trying to use the List Operations API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715318.aspx)

The request needs a parameter called 'subscription-id' - what is this? Is this related to the account/storage I am trying to query or is this specific to me? If it is the latter then how is security maintained?

My goal is to call the API from a C# WCF service.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SubscriptionId is a GUID that identifies a specific subscription. It is visible in several places in the Windows Azure Portal including the Dashboard tabs (bottom right) for Cloud Services and Storage Accounts.

Each Windows Azure subscription is uniquely identified by the SubscriptionId, which is a GUID. The Subscription Name is descriptive and is not necessarily unique. Knowledge of the SubscriptionId by itself is not particularly insecure since any operations against the Windows Azure Service Management REST API requires the use of an X.509 Certificate for authentication - and that does need to be secured since it (with the SubscriptionId) provides access to all Service Management operations.

I did a [post](http://convective.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/setting-an-endpoint-acl-on-a-windows-azure-vm/) recently describing the use of [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) to invoke Service Management operations - although the very popular [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home) works just as well. You may find the scriptability of these useful while you are ramping up your knowledge prior to using API in a WCF Service.

Comment: So for me to connect to these Azure storage I need a X509 certificate? Where do I get that from? Sorry for being such a newbie

Comment: The X.509 certificate is required ONLY for operations using the Windows Azure Service Management REST API. Individual Windows Azure features use different authentication mechanisms. The Storage Service uses an account name and account key specific to each storage account within the subscription. Once you create a storage account these become visible on the Windows Azure Portal.

I recommend you download the Windows Azure Training Kit which contains a wealth of material.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715318.aspx - I am trying to call the URI listed there but do not know what to enter as the subscription id - my subscription ID gives me an error, saying Forbidden

Comment: Th Forbidden error often indicates a problem with the X.509 certificate used to authenticate the request to the Service Management REST API. The certificate must be uploaded to the Settings/Management Certificates section of the portal or generated using the publish-settings file. The certificate must then be uploaded with the operation. You might find the following book chapter helpful: http://tinyurl.com/pn7shoc